# Como criar um banco de dados MySQL com comandos SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de saber como criar um banco de dados no MySQL usando comandos SQL, que eu possa rodar no MySQL Workbench, no phpMyAdmin ou em qualquer outro software.

Quais comandos SQL são necessários para criar um banco de dados e suas tabelas?

Answer (score 10):

O [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) e o [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) são apenas ferramentas visuais que oferecem praticidade/facilidade na manipulação de um banco de dados, os comandos SQL são independentes dele.

Dessa forma, assumindo que você está usando alguma versão do MySQL, para criar um banco de dados o comando é [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-database.html)

```
CREATE DATABASE meu_banco_de_dados
```

Para a criação de tabelas, utiliza-se o comando [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

```
CREATE TABLE minha_tabela (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    campo1 VARCHAR(50),
    campo2 INT,
    campo3 FLOAT
)
```

Comment: Muito boa a resposta, mostrou os comandos questionados, explicou e exemplificou de forma sucinta e objetiva.+1

Answer (score 4):

É fácil:

1. Crias a Base de Dados

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE NOME_DA_BASE_DE_DADOS
   ```
2. Usas a Base de Dados

   ```
   USE NOME_DA_BASE_DE_DADOS
   ```
3. Crias a tabela

   ```
   CREATE TABLE NOME_DA_TABELA (
     NOME_DO_CAMPO_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     NOME_DE_OUTRO_CAMPO INT,
     NOME_DE_OUTRO_CAMPO VARCHAR(255)
   )
   ```

Atenção que há vários tipos, eu é que só usei aqui o INT e o VARCHAR.